# Unordered List with no bullets not working with email template

Tags: visualforce, css, list, html, formatting

I have a Visualforce Component that has a un-ordered list. I want that list to have no style other then the indentation. Usually with HTML you would just specify the ul css to be `list-style:none` or `list-style-type:none`. It is not working for me for some reason. Can someone see what is going wrong here? Is it because I am using an in-line conditional style statement?

** I should also note that the component is being referenced in a visualforce email template. I think this might be the cause of the issue.**

I have tried:

- giving the ul a `class` and specifying in the style tag
- giving the ul an `id` and specifying in the style tag
- directly calling the `ul` in the style tag
- adding to the `li` inline style editing
- adding inline style directly to the `ul` tag

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
> p { font-size: 15px; font-family: "Arial", Times, serif; color: #141516;}
> #title {text-decoration: underline;}
> .center {text-align: center;}
> .displayinline{display: inline-block;}
> .floatRight {float: right;}
> .floatLeft {float: left;}
> .requiredGuarantor {padding-bottom: -1;}
> .ulist {list-style:none !important;}
> </style>
>
> <p><strong>Funding Conditions:</strong>
>     <ul class="ulist">
>        <li style="display: {!IF(cr.Credit_Stip1__c == null , 'none', 'block')}">{!cr.Credit_Stip1__c}</li>
>        ...
>  </p>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the bullet, just use the "ul" and its class name as shown below.

```
ul.ulist {list-style-type: none;}
```

Here is an example

```
    <apex:page controller="listStyleCon">
<style>
ul.thelist {list-style-type: none;}
</style>
<apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="account">
<ul class="thelist">
        <li>{!account.Name} </li>
        </ul>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```